# Coherence measurement for density matrix

Tags: entropy, decoherence, dynamics

I have a density matrix of the form:

$$\rho(t)=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} e^{-\frac{2 \tau ^{2 H+2}}{2 H+2}} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} e^{-\frac{2 \tau ^{2 H+2}}{2 H+2}} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6} e^{-\frac{2 \tau ^{2 H+2}}{2 H+2}} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} e^{-\frac{2 \tau ^{2 H+2}}{2 H+2}} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12} e^{-\frac{2 \tau ^{2 H+2}}{2 H+2}} \\
\end{array}
\right].$$

I want to quantify/observe the time evolution of coherence for this matrix showing dynamics of a quantum system between any two times $\tau_o$ and $\tau$ except using entropies. I will be thankful for your time and kind help.

Comment: What do you mean by “compute coherence”?

Comment: @Mauricio, This is a matrix showing dynamics of a quantum system. Thus, I am interested in to find the coherence value in the matrix at t=0 and at any other time t. As entanglement is measure by the concurrence or any other measure.

Comment: This review paper list a lot of [coherence measure](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02439). And I think you can start from a relatively easy one:$l_1$ norm-based coherence measure, i.e., $\sum_{i\neq j}|\rho_{ij}|$(eq.(38) in the link paper).

Comment: I don't understand. Are you looking to the entanglement, or the coherences? You want to compute the relative entropy of what exactly? And how do you define/quantify "coherence" here? And what issues precisely are you having in doing this?

Comment: @Attakhan what do you mean by "coherence value"? Do you have a formula? that would be useful to answer the question.

Comment: @narip Thank you very much for this suggestion. I will definitely look into that, as it listed a lot of measures of coherence.

Comment: @glS Thanks for your time and comment. Actually, I am willing to present how the coherence evolves with time and to compare it to the von-Neumann entropy. From this comparison, I want to draw some conclusions.

Comment: @Mauricio Thank you for your comment. Yes, I need a formula that can be useful to draw time evolution of a coherence in a  quantum system. If you have something in your mind regarding this, please add it here.

Comment: Where is the time dependence in that density matrix? Do you have a Hamiltonian? And what is $\beta$?

Comment: @Mauricio, I have added the complete density matrix, please read it. Thank you for the kind concerns and time.

Comment: $H$ is the Hamiltonian?

Comment: @Mauricio, here, $H$ is the Hurst index parameter of the fractional Gaussian noise. The matrix, I have included above already contain the Hamiltonian and time unitary operation obtained by $\rho(t)=U(t) \rho_o U^{\dagger}(t)$, where, $U(t)=e^{-i \mathcal{H}(t)}$ and here, $\mathcal{H}(t)$ is the Hamiltonian, which is already present in the above given matrix. Thanks for your time.